# convert image into html sections

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to convert image into HTML sections ( see image below marked as red , blue , orange , green and yellow). That means when i click on these parts they will appear as a separate section in a separate window just like online news paper.

Well one can do this by using photoshop slicing tool may be m not sure.. but don't want to use photoshop rather i want to implement such functionality where i can select the section over image and then later on it will get convert into html page or part.

so can anyone give me some idea , example or a road map to do that

[image]

Comment: You want to do this on the client with JS? You'll use pixel coordinates as the input?

Comment: You're looking for imagemap (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp)  Technology as old as the hills, relatively speaking.

Comment: I think he wants something to create the map from a browser, upload the big image, then let the user drag around to create the hotspots. @Hunt, can you comment?

Comment: @Juan Mendes yes you are right , i want to give user a control to upload an image and then sectioned the part they want to

Comment: Are you asking about an automated process that transforms your images into an html document containing the text and the images of what you just clicked on?

Comment: @Hun: your answer is not clear, do you want the image converted into HTML text? or do you just want to be able to link to different documents when clicking different areas of the image? If you just want the image to link to multiple documents, use the tools mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the simplest task, luckily, there are plenty of tools that do what you want (generate the map that creates the hotspots for your image)

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

http://www.image-maps.com/ This one lets you use an existing map and modify it.

and many others http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=online+image+map+creator

If you want to be able to click and link just to that part of the image you have two options:

- Write some server side code that does the slicing of images, based on the map coordinates. There are many libraries available to do this, in PHP, there's GD http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php and http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php which can run on many platforms.
- When you click on an image, pass the map coordinates to the new page, and position the image using a window technique, much like css sprites. http://websitetips.com/articles/css/sprites/

Comment: i tried the tool that you have suggested me , well i want that functionality plus i want to show the mapped section into another window when user clicks on the selected or diced area.

Comment: Well  , do have any idea what sort of technology is required on the server side to diced the image according to coordinates.